# When is the "Fast Integer Multiplication Using Modular Arithmetic" (2008) algorithm faster than Schönhage-Strassen algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, biginteger, multiplication, modular

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods):

"Anindya De, Chandan Saha, Piyush Kurur and Ramprasad Saptharishi[11] gave a similar algorithm using modular arithmetic in 2008 achieving the same running time. However, these latter algorithms are only faster than Schönhage–Strassen *for impractically large inputs*."

I would be very interested in the size of such *impractically large* integers.

Maybe someone did implement both algorithms in a certain way and could do some benchmarks?

Thanks

Comment: Fürer's algorithm and it's modular equivalent... very deep research topic. Nobody actually knows how big the cross-over point is. And it's likely to be highly sensitive to hardware and implementation details. In any case, that might be completely irrelevant since that cross-over point is likely to be well beyond 64-bit computing limits.

Comment: @Mysticial: Care to explain how this question is relevant to whether ones uses 8-bit, 64-bit or 1024-bit ?

Comment: Basically, the cross-over point is so large that it would require more memory than what 64-bit allows. And since 128-bit hardware is virtually non-existent, it's pointless to speculate exactly where that cross-over point is because it will be extremely sensitive to details of the (currently non-existent) hardware. Even a factor of 2 in the big-O constant could mean a several orders of magnitude difference in the cross-over point.

Comment: @Mysticial: I understand your point. However, there must be some "non-mathematical" threshold for a given implementation. I edited my question to specify this.

Comment: @TeaBee: "there must be ..." Would you care to justify this assumption?

Comment: You need to find n such that log(log n)>c2^(log* n), where c is quotient of the constants. Assuming that c=100, you get n > 2^(2^100), a number not that will not fit in 64 bit hardware. I speculate the constant will be higher than 100.

Comment: @NiklasB.: From the proof of complexity stating that the DSKS (I call it this way) algorithm has the same complexity as Fürer's that is n log(n) 2Θ(log*(n)) where as Schönhage-Strassen algorithm has a greater complexity of Θ(n log(n) log(log(n))).

Comment: @TeaBee: That doesn't mean that an implementation of Fürer exists that's actually faster for some testable input. Maybe you have a misunderstanding in what the O-notation means: The two algorithms could well differ by a constant factor that's in the billions or even larger.

Comment: @NiklasB.: You're correct. My misunderstanding indeed :)

Comment: @sdcvvc: So according to your calculation, the multiplication of numbers with billions of digits is still less efficient with the DSKS algorithm than with the Schönhage-Strassen algorithm. Am I correct?

Comment: TeaBee: Yes. If your number has "only" 10^20 digits, then n=10^(10^20) ~ 2^(2^68) and the quotient of constants would need to be less than 2!

Comment: I'm familiar with both Schönhage-Strassen and Fürer's algorithm. I've implemented Schönhage-Strassen and I understand how Fürer's algorithm works. It's very possible that the cross-over point is so high that a computer capable of holding the parameters will be larger than the size of the observable universe. That's the problem when you have complexities that differ by less than a logarithm. It takes exponentially large input sizes to compensate even for small differences in the Big-O constant. In this case, Fürer's algorithm is known to have a *very very very* large Big-O constant.

Comment: @Mysticial you should post all the above as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fürer's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm) and it's modular equivalent (DSKS) are very deep research topics and, for now, remain only as academic interest. Nobody actually knows how big the cross-over point is. And in all likeliness it doesn't matter because that cross-over point is likely to be ***well beyond 64-bit computing limits***.

I've implemented Schönhage-Strassen before and I understand how Fürer's algorithm works. So I'm quite familiar with both of them. I can say it's very possible that the cross-over point between Schönhage-Strassen and Fürer's algorithm is so high that a computer capable of holding the parameters will be larger than the size of the observable universe.

That's the problem when you have complexities that differ by less than a logarithm. ***It takes exponentially large input sizes to compensate even for small differences in the Big-O constant.***

In this case, Fürer's algorithm is known to have a *very very very* large Big-O constant.